# multiple TextView in listactvity

Tags: android

Please see the xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:textSize="50px"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="TextView" 
android:id="@+id/label2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

also see the java code

```
    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
IconicAdapter(){
    super(NewOrderActivity.this,R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.label1,ordersId);


}// end of the constrcutor
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

    View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    TextView t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label1);
TextView t1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label2);

    OrdersData d=(OrdersData)dataVector.elementAt(position);

    t.setText(d.order_id);
    t.setText(d.orderdate);


    return (row);

}

}
```

I want to add two textview where i can set text but application crashes when i am retrieving these texview using findviewById
Please help how can I set two textviews in a row of ListActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getView()` method. You are doing wrong there..

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

  if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            TextView t=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label1);
                TextView t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
       }

     OrdersData d=(OrdersData)dataVector.elementAt(position);

    t.setText(d.order_id);
    t1.setText(d.orderdate);

    return (convertView);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the getView() of the adapter in a wrong way.

For accessing the layout you have to do something like this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Hope this helps!